# azure-devops: creating new work item link-types

Tags: azure

Is there a possibility to create new/individual link types for azure board work items (in addition to child/parent, related, successor/predesessor)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you are on the server product, not in cloud. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/customize-work?view=azure-devops-2022#collection-level-process-customization
Look for the entry "Support for customizing link types".